# Only change position of editText when typing android

Tags: android

When I am in my app and I want to type the keyboard pops up but also all the elements in the app go up. I would like to know how I can only make the editText and its button go up and let the other elements keep their position. This is my code (just began coding):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jochem.chatbot.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:onClick="changeText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:hint="Yeah, typ something"
        android:textColorHint="#505050"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Typ something"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Okay, I did it!

Comment: Can you try by adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" this attribute in your <activity> tag in Manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me works adding 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest for `<activity>` tag.

Here you have docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html